# Illustrations of quantum circuits in doxygen documentation

Tags: iframe

I would like to add illustrations of quantum gates and circuits into my doxygen documentation.

First, I tried to create illustrations of quantum circuits using the LaTeX package [Quantikz](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/quantikz/manual.pdf) but I could not find a way to get them displayed in the HTML output of doxygen.

My second attempt was to embed an external website that can visualise quantum circuits in the browser, namely, [Quirk](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:[[%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22]]%7D) into the documentation via the  tag. This tag is, however, not supported by doxygen. 
1) Quirk is open-source (Apache License 2.0) so redirecting to it should be permitted. 2) This also enables the local installation of Quirk on the web server where the documentation is hosted to circumvent problems due to changing URL structures or APIs.

Any help in either getting one of the above options working or suggestions to create illustrations of quantum circuits in the documentation is highly appreciated.

Comment: 1) This may violate the terms and conditions for that site and their content and so you should start by asking them. 2) If you get this working, it will stop working the moment that site changes their URL structure or any of several other characteristics. 3) What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do not add additional information in comments please. Use the EDIT button to add this and other information to the body of the question itself so that the question is improved and people do not have to read the comments to understand the question. And please answer all of the questions I asked above.